How can i view , copy files to an Azure Function app?
I have a function app in Azure, I usually use filezilla to copy file and upload files to the function app. But for some reason when i connect , i cant see the files under wwwroot ?
I have tried to use Kudu, but that is not reliable , limited in some areas
Why does this happen with a function app and how can i view files ?

Can You share your code

code ? there is no code ... all i want to do is use filezilla or any other app to view my files . When i connect i cant see files under wwwroot. it works for app services but dont seem to work for function apps in azure ?

Which app service plan you are using for function? and is  it a  Linux or Windows based?

You cannot check files if function is deployed using consumption service plan with linux, whereas you can check build files in windows in Kudu console.
To check build files for linux using kudu you  need to deploy function in Premium plan or App Service plan.
LINUX:

Note :- You cannot add or upload file in Linux on consumption plan


You can directly upload files in  Kudu:
WINDOWS:

Note :- You need to drag and drop files or folder at the top to upload.


LINUX_with_Premium:
open Kudu adding /newui to the kudu url for new ui.

Note :- As you can see it gives you option to select or drag n drop option.


